# NiFi | How to replace text based on length of field in JSON records

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have data coming into NiFi in JSON format. Below is the sample

```
{
  "company_name": "mycompany",
  "companytyp": "producer",
  "Welcomemes": "welcome_message1",
  "logo": "//somepath/to/logo URL "
}
```

I have been trying to apply a JOLT transformation for the following condition:

- If the length of logo field is more than 10 characters then replace it with blank value
- If the length of logo field is less than or equal to 10 characters then keep the provided value

I have not been able to achieve this. Would really appreciate some help & guidance. I am open to using any other processor too but the preference will be JOLT transformation

**Input 1:**

```json
{
  "company_name": "mycompany",
  "companytyp": "producer",
  "Welcomemes": "welcome_message1",
  "logo": "This logo value is more than 10 characters "
}
```

**Expected Output 1**

```json
{
  "company_name": "mycompany",
  "companytyp": "producer",
  "Welcomemes": "welcome_message1",
  "logo": ""
}
```

**Input 2:**

```
  "company_name": "mycompany",
  "companytyp": "producer",
  "Welcomemes": "welcome_message1",
  "logo": "short logo"
}
```

**Expected Output 2**

```json
{
  "company_name": "mycompany",
  "companytyp": "producer",
  "Welcomemes": "welcome_message1",
  "logo": "short logo"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to put in an empty string but this spec will replace those `logo` fields with a single space:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "logo": "=substring(@(1,logo),0,11)",
      "logo_size": "=size(@(1,logo))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "logo_size": {
        "11": {
          "# ": "logo"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,logo)": "logo"
        }
      },
      "logo": null,
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Thank you so much!!! I edited the spec to replace the whitespace out. My not be elegant but performing the trim operation removes the white space.  'code' [
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "logo": "=trim"
    }
  }]

Answer (score 0):

This is the final spec based on solution provided by @mattyb

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "logo": "=substring(@(1,logo),0,11)",
      "logo_size": "=size(@(1,logo))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "logo_size": {
        "11": {
          "# ": "logo"
        },
        "*": {
          "@(2,logo)": "logo"
        }
      },
      "logo": null,
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "logo": "=trim"
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Hi Aditya . Be aware that the **trim** function trims in an case, eg. whether the size is less than 11.

Comment: Btw, will you have any `"logo": null`, and if so do you need to convert them to `"logo": ""` as well ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I liked your input. Thank you. However, out of curiosity-would the trim not work like this (a) if the value in logo field is more than 10 characters then blank space will be passed in logo field which after trimming will remove the blank space. (b) if the logo field originally has less than equal to 10 characters then original value will be passes and it will be trimmed. Either case It will satisfy the requirement. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sure there's no problem with `(a)`, but if you say either for `(b)`, then nothing to say left more for me. OK, have a nice day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The **trim** function trims in an case even if the length of the **logo**'s value is less than 11. For example : **`"logo":" abc "`** will be converted eventually to **`"logo":"abc"`**

You can try to convert the related value to **null** for the cases with the length more than 10, presuming that you have ***quoted*** values for the attribute **logo** for each case.

So, you might consider using the following one :

```json
[
  { // prepare the criteria of the string length comparison to be used within the the next spec
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": { 
      "logo_size": "=size(@(1,logo))",
      "x": "=intSum(-10,@(1,logo_size))",
      "xAbs": "=abs(@(1,x))",
      "sz": ["=divide(@(1,x),@(1,xAbs))", -1.0]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*om*": "&",
      "sz": {
        "*": {
          "@": "logo"
        },
        "-1.0": { // the negative approach is used to determine the cases in which the related length exceeds ten
          "@2,logo": "logo"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert the values to blanks for the null-valued logo attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "logo": ["=notNull", ""]
    }
  }
]
```